# How to call function only once in resize function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, resize

Any idea how I can make a function be called only once using .resize, and then have it permanently cancelled or disabled?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        size = true;
        mob();
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Great stuff, thanks **sdespont** - got it to work with on/off:

```
$(window).on('resize',function () {
            if ($(window).width() < 800){
                    agent = true;
                    mob();
            }
            });
```

then turn off the resize function once the condition is met:

```
$(window).off('resize');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `one` function http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$(window).one('resize',function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 800){
        size = true;
        mob();
    }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Or `on/off` functions http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(window).on('resize',function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 800){
        size = true;
        mob();
    }
});

$(window).trigger('resize').off('resize');
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has the [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method for that:

```
$(window).one("resize", function () { /* */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems it doesn't work well with resize, function only fires if the browser window is already smaller than 800 not larger.

Comment: I doubt that's related to the window's width. Maybe it's because the `resize` event usually fires multiple times *while* you're resizing, so it doesn't work to have it fire only once. Instead, we'd need to find a way to detect the end of a resizing "gesture", or something.